# Set Clion on Windows 10

Tags: clion

I was configuring Clion by following a guide here on StackOverflow, but I have a problem. The section about make, C compiler, and C++ compiler have some problems, but I don't understand what I should do.

[image]

Notice the "Test CMake run finished with error" message. When I click on "more...", I see this:

```
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is unknown
CMake Warning at /cygdrive/c/Users/SpeedHunter/.CLion2018.1/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.10.3/Modules/Platform/CYGWIN.cmake:15 (message):
  CMake no longer defines WIN32 on Cygwin!

  (1) If you are just trying to build this project, ignore this warning or
  quiet it by setting CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=0 in your environment or in
  the CMake cache.  If later configuration or build errors occur then this
  project may have been written under the assumption that Cygwin is WIN32.
  In that case, set CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32=1 instead.

  (2) If you are developing this project, add the line

    set(CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 0) # Remove when CMake >= 2.8.4 is required

  at the top of your top-level CMakeLists.txt file or set the minimum
  required version of CMake to 2.8.4 or higher.  Then teach your project to
  build on Cygwin without WIN32.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /cygdrive/c/Users/SpeedHunter/.CLion2018.1/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.10.3/Modules/CMakeSystemSpecificInformation.cmake:26 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- broken
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/SpeedHunter/.CLion2018.1/system/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.10.3/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

It fails with the following output:

Change Dir: /cygdrive/c/Users/SpeedHunter/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make.exe" "cmTC_4ca12/fast"

CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
 CMakeLists.txt:1 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/SpeedHunter/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/c/Users/SpeedHunter/AppData/Local/Temp/cmake_check_environment/_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

Error code: 1
```

What should I do?

Comment: You should post the specific problem in your question

Comment: Ok, sorry when i Click on more, I have this:

https://nopaste.xyz/?045309f6c0b35363#o5Q6Wzld6YxZXG8LR5jTF5MrfwNMbuI51L5PPth2K0w=

Comment: Sorry I posted an image, but i didn't know I can't. I edited original post.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with posting images if it clarifies the question